# How to properly deal with and possibly normalize non-english characters in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2005

I have some odd data which i am putting in an xml file (ansi/utf-8).

I am having trouble with symbols that web browsers cannot parse.
Here is an example of the troublesome data:

```
ColumnA
no sería tan divertido
```

Here is my select Statement:

```
SELECT
        'test'          as 'node/@attribute'
        ,Column_A       as 'node'
FROM
        TableA      
for xml PATH('record'), ROOT('log')
```

And here is the error i get when FF or IE try to open the document:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
```

and then it will subsequently point me to the above data.

Is there a way normalize all text in ColumnA to avoid this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: What text encoding do you have activated in IE or FF?  UTF-8 should definitely be able to handle this kind of content....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With None encoding everything is just fine

The query

```
SELECT TOP 1 
        'test'          as 'node/@attribute'
        ,N'no sería tan divertido'       as 'node'   
for xml PATH('record'), ROOT('log')
```

The xml

```
<log>
  <record>
    <node attribute="test">no sería tan divertido</node>
  </record>
</log>
```

IE

[image]